# How to replace right most string in SQL

Tags: sql-server, replace

I want to replace rightmost same characters from string.
e.g string is like in this format

```
"GGENXG00126""XLOXXXXX"
```

in sql but last consecutive X lenght is not fix.

I already Tried in  SQL is

```
select REPLACE('"GGENXG00126""XLOXXXXX"', 'X', '')
```

but using this all 'X' is removed. I want to remove only rightmost same characters and output expected "GGENG00126""LO".

Comment: Regex replacement could easily handle this requirement, but unfortunately SQL Server does not really have good regex support.

Comment: For a regex solution, find `(.)\1*"$` and replace with `"`

Comment: thanks for replay but I need to implement in sql.

Comment: @Cid Thanks, I corrected my comment (looks right to me now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all `x` with spaces, `RTRIM`, then undo the replacements:

```
SELECT '"' + REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(str, 2, LEN(str) - 2), 'X', ' ')), ' ', 'X') + '"'
FROM (VALUES
    ('"GGENXG00126""XLOXXXXX"')
) v(str)
-- "GGENXG00126""XLO"
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative idea using `PATINDEX` and `REVERSE`, to find the first character that isn't the final character in the string. (*Assumes* all strings are quoted):

```
SELECT REVERSE(STUFF(R.ReverseString,1,PATINDEX('%[^' + LEFT(R.ReverseString,1) + ']%',R.ReverseString)-1,'')) + '"'
FROM (VALUES('"GGENXG00126""XLOXXXXX"'))V(YourString)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(STUFF(REVERSE(V.YourString),1,1,''))) R(ReverseString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below option-

```
DECLARE @InputString VARCHAR(200) = 'GGENXG00126""XLOXXXXX'

SELECT 
LEFT(
    @InputString,
    LEN(@InputString)+
        1-
        PATINDEX(
            '%[^X]%', 
            REVERSE(@InputString)
        )
)
```

Output is-

```
GGENXG00126""XLO
```